# Fast matrix computation in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to compute:

[image]

I can further decompose this into:

[image]

In R I wrote this code

```
att_num <- dim(X)[2]
A <- matrix(0, att_num, att_num)
for(i in seq(att_num)) A[,i] <- colSums(dx * X * X[,i])
```

But it is TERRIBLE slow because of the loop. This line is taking most of the computing time in my script. Is there a way I can improve this computation?

- `dx` is a vector of size [1 x m]
- `X` is a matrix of size [n x m]

Example:

```
dx <- sample(1:100, 30, replace=T)
X <- data.frame(replicate(30,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))

att_num <- dim(X)[2]
A <- matrix(0, att_num, att_num)
for(i in seq(att_num)) A[,i] <- colSums(dx * X * X[,i])
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: `crossprod(dx*X, X)`

Comment: Note that the length of `dx` doesn't fit with the number of observations in `X`. It is recycled, which might or might not be what you need. Also, I'm not sure if your code implements the equation correcty.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the length of `dx` does **always** fit with the number of observations in `X`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
dx <- sample(1:100, 30, replace=T)
X <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,100,rep=TRUE)))

att_num <- dim(X)[2]
A <- matrix(0, att_num, att_num)
for(i in seq(att_num)) A[,i] <- colSums(dx * X * X[,i])

B <- crossprod(as.matrix(dx * X), as.matrix(X))

all.equal(A, unname(B))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x_i are the columns of X, then you can do it in a vectorized fashion using the matrix multiplication operator `%*%`:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1234)
nrows <- 100
ncols <- 30 # same as length(dx)
dx <- sample(1:100, ncols, replace=T)
X <- matrix(sample(0:1, nrows*ncols, replace = TRUE), nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols)
A <- X %*% Diagonal(length(dx), dx) %*% t(X)
```

If X has a ton of zeros, I would highly recommend that you put it in a sparse format (check out `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package). Note that the diagonal matrix in the middle is actually sparse. This saves **A LOT** of memory and computation.

**NOTE 1:** In the comments below, Roland noted that dx is not as long as X has rows. I would suggest checking exactly what you want to do because usually that should be the case! Also, normally x_i are the columns of X. If you post more information (including for example the limits of the index in the sum), I can help you more.

**NOTE 2:** Also, try using matrices instead of data frames. Data frames are a lot slower because they have to manage the columns separately.

Comment: Note that `nrow(X) != length(dx)` in their example.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks. Normally I would think in such calculations you would have that X has as many columns as d is long though, because it looks as though you are calculating the weighted (with D = diag(d)) covariance matrix of X, right?

Comment: Yes, I find this discrepancy confusing too.

Comment: The thing is, if the length difference were actually the case, the correct code would vary depending if dx is shorter / longer than `nrow(X)` or if you wanted to recycle it as you commented in the question, etc.